# Spring Hibernate - Fetch column value using @Formula from max value based of other table

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have two tables with one to many relation. Lead and Leadactivity. A lead can have multiple activities.

Problem Statement -
I want an additional column in lead table to know the last modified date of any lead. Last modified date will be the date when last activity was created or updated. So, I am using @Formula to fetch the column. However, I am not able to get the correct date instead I am getting null value for field lastModifiedDate. Can anyone help where I am going wrong. Below are the table structure

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "customer_lead")
@Where(clause = ReusableFields.SOFT_DELETED_CLAUSE)
@Audited(withModifiedFlag = true)
@Data
public class Lead extends ReusableFields implements Serializable
{
    //other fields 

    @NotAudited
    @Formula("(Select max(modified) from lead_activity la Where la.lead_id=lead_id)")
    Date lastModifiedDate;
}
```

Lead Activity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "LeadActivity")
@Data
@Where(clause = ReusableFields.SOFT_DELETED_CLAUSE)
public class LeadActivity extends ReusableFields implements Serializable
{
    // other fields

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "lead_id", nullable = false)
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(
    { "hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler" })
    @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    Lead lead;

}
```

Mapped super class for modified field

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Audited
public class ReusableFields implements Serializable
{

    public static final String SOFT_DELETED_CLAUSE = "is_deleted = 'false'";

    
    @Column(name="is_deleted", columnDefinition="BOOLEAN DEFAULT true")
    public boolean isDeleted;

    @CreationTimestamp
    @Column(name = "created_at")
    @JsonProperty("created")
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ")
    private Date created;
    
    @Column(name = "updated_at")
    @JsonProperty("updated")
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    @UpdateTimestamp
    private Date modified;
    
    public Date getCreated() {
        return created;
    }

    public void setCreated(Date created) {
        this.created = created;
    }

    public Date getModified() {
        return modified;
    }

    public void setModified(Date modified) {
        this.modified = modified;
    }

    public boolean isDeleted() {
        return isDeleted;
    }

    public void setDeleted(boolean isDeleted) {
        this.isDeleted = isDeleted;
    }

    public static String getSoftDeletedClause() {
        return SOFT_DELETED_CLAUSE;
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handled this by adding below formula

@NotAudited
@Formula("(Select max(la.updated_at) from Lead_Activity la Where la.lead_id=lead_id)")
Date lastModifiedDate;